# iOS5 SDK, Core Data, and creating a new DB. Bizarre issue

Tags: xcode, core-data, ios5

I'm having a bizarre issue. I'm writing a method that handles the creation of a DB with core data that first checks to see if the db exists prior to either opening it (if found) or creating it (if not found). Here is the code:

```
- (void) loadClubs
{
    NSLog(@"Checking for club database.");

    NSLog(@"file url: %@", self.clubDatabase.fileURL.path);


    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.clubDatabase.fileURL path]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Creating club database.");

        //_clubDatabase saveToURL:<#(NSURL *)#> forSaveOperation:<#(UIDocumentSaveOperation)#> completionHandler:<#^(BOOL success)completionHandler#>

        [self.clubDatabase saveToURL: self.clubDatabase.fileURL forSaveOperation: UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
            NSLog(@"test");
        }];
            //NSLog(@"Created new database.");
            //[self fetchClubData:self.clubDatabase];


    }
    else if (self.clubDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed)
    {
        NSLog(@"Opening club database.");

        [self.clubDatabase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Opened club database.");
            [self fetchClubData:self.clubDatabase];
        }];
    }
    else if (self.clubDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal)
    {
        [self fetchClubData:self.clubDatabase];
        NSLog(@"Club database is open. Proceeding as normal.");
    }
}
```

But I'm having a really strange issue: when I call [self.clubDatabase saveToURL: self.clubDatabase.fileURL forSaveOperation: UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success)... the completion handler doesn't execute!! I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this. Any thoughts?

I've tried:

- Stepping through on GDB
- Calling _clubDatabase rather than fetching
  using the getter
- Testing other completion handlers in Core Data (which
  work!)

I have no idea what's causing this. Any thoughts?

Thanks much!!

-Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, for others experiencing something similar, I think I've had my "aha!" moment. It seems that saveToURL runs asynchronously and thus a bug in the viewcontroller called after this method (sequentially) may be causing a crash and thus prventing the completion handler from ever being called. I have to verify this, but it's the only thing that makes sense at this point.